# Pop-Up Sticky Footer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a sticky footer that pop up when the user scrolling the page to the bottom, but i want the footer to stay behind the content.

for the pop-up part i use css :

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;    
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
}
```

and jquery :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {          
        $('#footer').show();
    }
});
```

My problem is when the footer pop-up, the content is stay-behind the footer, i try z-index: -1 for the footer, but the content is overlaping with the footer. How can i achieve this :

** First Step : User Scrolling Down
** When reach bottom, footer pop-up and the content is push-up
** When user scrolling up, the footer stay behind the content

[image]

Comment: Just asking but why wouldn't you use wow.js? http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

Comment: can you show your markup or do it in a working snippet or fiddle?

Comment: Hey, I have found a pure CSS answer to your exact question while I was searching for a similar thing, if you or OP are searching: https://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/slideout-footer-css ...There is a demo there too.